# How do I open an already created project in Android Studio from the terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio

How do I open an already created android project from the terminal in Ubuntu (or other Linux system, if different) into Android Studio?

For instance I have a project named JustJava located in
/home/me/AndroidStudioProjects/JustJava
How do I open it in Android Studio from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

```
/home/user_name/bin/android-studio/bin/studio.sh 
/home/user_name/AndroidStudioProjects/JustJava 
&> /dev/null &
```

Where you replace user_name by whatever the computer's user name is, and replace the locations of studio.sh and JustJava if they were installed outside of the default directories. The line

```
&> /dev/null
```

sends all the annoying error messages to a black hole, and the trailing ampersand

```
&
```

opens Android Studio in a way that allows you to continue to operate on the terminal while it's running.